# How to get an instance attribute which is the name of the instance itself?

Tags: python

I have a Python class named `myClass` having one argument or more, say `a`, and an instance which I call `obj`, as follows:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        ...
    def method1(self):
        ...

obj = myClass(3)
```

I want `obj` to have an *attribute* which is a string with the name of the instance itself, even without passing that name as instance argument, as follows:

```
>>> obj = myClass(3)
>>> obj.name
"obj"
```

From my experience, there is no way to get it via chatGPT. Could you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, which (zero, one or many) identifier(s) an object is assigned to aren't properties of the object itself. What's the _context_, the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](/q/18425225/4518341) I recommend [kindall's answer](/a/18425275/4518341).

Comment: "I want "obj" having an ATTRIBUTE which is a string with the name of the instance itself" This already makes no sense, because "the instance itself" **does not have** a name, and in particular, `obj` **is not** "the name of the instance". Any number of *references to* the object can exist; the `obj` variable is not special in that regard. In particular, if we write `obj2 = obj`, then now we have two variables that mean **the same object (not a copy)**, so there is no way to expect "the name of the instance" to mean a variable name.

Comment: "From my experience, there is no way to get it via chatGPT" - well, yes; ChatGPT isn't part of your program. But less facetiously: ChatGPT [**cannot write nor explain code for you, it can only create the illusion of doing so**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUrOxh_0leE).

Comment: If you want to have a string name to connect with your object it is easiest to keep your objects in a dictionary.  `myobjects['obj'] = myClass(3)`

Comment: An object doesn't have a "name". If you don't somehow attach an attribute with teh string you want, then the object has no knowledge of the (potentially various) variables that may refer to it at a given time. And there aren't any reasonable ways to go about retrieving those names. The *sane* way is to explicitly make an association between your object and a string object.

Comment: And the instance may never be assign to a name, e.g. if you create a bunch of instances in a list comprehension. Your queston more or less suggest there is something wrong with what ypou do and probably this is XY question. Your code should not care about the name used for specific object.

Comment: If I have to guess, you either try to have names created dynamically or have some information embedded in them Mandatory Ned Batchelder
's [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: What would be the name if one did `foo = [myClass(3)]`?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Kind of a round about way to do it but this should work. Class object keeps track of all instance of the object, and each instance has a unique id. We can then check `globals` and compare instance types and ids to find the correct variable name.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def get_name(self):
        for k in globals():
            if self is globals()[k]:
                return k
```

Comment: what if the instance is not in `globals()`?

Comment: also you could just use `if self is globals()[k]` and ditch all that rigamarole with an `__id`

Comment: shoot you're right. ill update!

Comment: *"Class object keeps track of all instance of the object"* - I don't see that.

Comment: I edited with corrections reflecting comments but someone yeeted them with a new edit to correct my grammar..